# Using Harfbuzz with Freetype2 cache (FTC)

Tags: freetype, freetype2, harfbuzz

I'm currently using Harfbuzz and Freetype cache, using FTC_ImageCache_Lookup to get my glyphs. As per FreeTypes documentation, we should not call FT_Set_Char_Size when using its cache [(see here)](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Set_Char_Size). Instead FTC_ImageCache_Lookup receives the requested height for the glyph.

The issue is that without setting the font size, Harfbuzz will fail to compute the correct positioning for some glyphs (for example, the 'SARA U' glyph).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with FTC yet but I guess you can easily set font size on HarfBuzz indepedently by following [this](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz-tutorial/blob/master/hello-harfbuzz-opentype.c#L28-L29), basically setting HarfBuzz's ot-func instead Freetype by `hb_ot_font_set_funcs` (maybe not needed even) and `hb_font_set_scale` to set the font size.